# May a Czech Citizen living in the UK Apply in the UK for South Korean visa?

Tags: visa, south-korea

I am an EU student (Czech citizen) studying in Britain. That means that I don't need to prove that I am a resident as I can spend an unlimited time in the UK. However, I am planning to go to study in South Korea for a year as an exchange student.

The South Korean Embassy in the Czech Republic told me that it would be much easier for me to apply for a visa here in Britain. Will I be able to apply for a South Korean visa here despite the fact that I am not a British citizen? I don't have a resident card, but I can show a tenancy agreement or bills to prove that I live here.

Comment: "The South Korean Embassy in the Czech Republic told me that it would be much easier for me to apply for a visa here in Britain": surely they never would have told you such a thing if your citizenship prevents you from applying in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the university in Britain to include your address in the UK onto the student verification letter when you apply for a visa in the UK. Maybe the address on the bank statement when you apply as proof of sufficient funds.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why the South Korean embassy would not allow you to apply in the UK as an EU citizen. They are familiar with the fact that all EU citizens are generally permitted to remain in other member states for as long as they desire.

I'm not sure if South Korea has the same notice, however the US Embassy in London says that you need to prove your status in the UK unless you are a British or EU citizen. Furthermore, I myself as an EU citizen in the UK applied for many visas over the years and my immigration status was never brought up.